# Why does my Next.js app is not deploying on Vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy a Next.js app on Vercel, but I get this error: `Error: Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name`.

Apparently the problem comes from the page `pages/_document.js`, which I copied from here [Next.js GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js). Can someone help me to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It is an ESLint error, and has nothing to do with the `_document` that you have linked to. Paste the whole error message and the related code. Also once refer the [docs](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/display-name.md) to figure what you might be doing wrong. You can also disable linting before build. [Ref.](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-eslint)

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992932/component-definition-is-missing-display-name-react-display-name.