# eslint: Component Definition is missing displayName

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, material-table

Using material-table (https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding), I'm trying to override a certain component of a table. It renders just fine, but I'd like to get rid of the eslint error intellij throws at me without just ignoring/disabling it.

Erorr:

> ESLint: Component definition is missing display
>   name(react/display-name)

```
  ...
  return (
    <div className={classes.rootDiv}>
      <div className={classes.mainTableContainer}>
        <MainTable
          components={{
            Settings: (props) => <TableSettings name={'Steven'} {...props} /> // <- Error near (props)
          }}
          ...
```

Tablesettings

```
import React from 'react';

const TableSettings = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TableSettings;
```

Comment: does these answer your question? [eslint-github-discussion](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/597) or [setting-displayName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356073/how-to-set-displayname-in-a-functional-component-react)

Comment: Thanks buzatto, but sadly neither the two links nor many other threads I've googled so far made it clear to me what the proper solution is.

Comment: I would guess that the function `(props) => <TableSettings name={'Steven'} {...props} />` is treated (actually it is) as component definition itself, hence the error would be related to that anonymous arrow function component. you may overcome passing a named function component like:`Settings: TableSettings` or wrapping TableSettings in another one then calling `Settings: TableSettingsWrapper`

Answer (score 10):

to ignore this rule as you want, you need to set your `.eslintrc.json` as:

```
{
  // other configs...,
  "rules": {
    "react/display-name": "off"
  }
}
```

[more about it](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/display-name.md)

Comment: Appreciate the help! Turning the setting off, whilst being the last resort, is something I'd like to avoid. I'd rather understand and fix my error than make it go away silently. If no one has a tip what might fix it properly, I'll use that one, though. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can disable file level this rule writting on the first line of the file:

```
/* eslint-disable react/display-name */
```