# Enzyme don't work with script "yarn test --coverage"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, test-coverage

I tried to test my react project with enzyme and jest, when run my project with `yarn test` all be right, but when I tried to run the coverage report with the script `yarn test --coverage` and all test with enzyme has been failed.

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

import {configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import 'jest-enzyme';


configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
```

This is my test.

```
it("should render Form", () => {
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.exists(FormSignup)).toBe(true);
  });
```

When I run with `yarn test` and y try to log `wrapper.debug()`

```
Console.log src/pages/patient-auth/patient-auth.test.js:99
      <div class="sc-iwaifL fibzQF"><div class="sc-cxNIbT dbZAGD">
<h3>Authorización de paciente</h3></div><div class="sc-lmgQde gQjQQD">
<form autoComplete="off" class="sc-fKgIGh fFDhjo">
<div class="sc-bCwgka cYnlCt"><div><h4>Nombre: test test test</h4>
<h4>Correo : test@test.com</h4></div></div><div class="sc-bCwgka cYnlCt">
<div class="sc-gtssRu cHOYTA"><input type="date" name="expiration_date" min="1980-01-01" max="2021-01-19" class="sc-dlnjPT lbPlE"/>
<label class="sc-hKFyIo htgnEd shrink">Fecha de expiración</label></div><div class="sc-kEqYlL jRpfDg"> <div class="sc-jSFkmK hwcRol"><span> Autorización</span></div><div class="sc-gKAblj fxkdfC"><input type="checkbox" name="auth" id="auth" class="sc-jrsJCI iFWYuj"/><label for="auth" class="sc-iCoHVE gpnzXF"><span data-yes="Si" data-no="No" class="sc-fujyUd bbprCb"></span><label class="sc-pNWxx fvvsLs"></label></label></div></div> </div><button type="submit" class="sc-bdnylx jqdcFs">&quot;Actualizar Paciente&quot;</button><div style="max-width:100%"><p style="font-size:10px">{&quot;expiration_date&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;auth&quot;:null}</p>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="sc-iJCRLp iZsMhV"></div></div>
```

and the test is right

When I run with `yarn test --coverage` and y try to log `wrapper.debug()`

```
console.log src/pages/patient-auth/patient-auth.test.js:99
      null

 expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      103 | 
      104 |   it("should render Form", () => {
    > 105 |     expect(wrapper.exists(FormSignup)).toBe(true);
          |                                        ^
      106 |   });
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the `test` script in your package.json? And what is `wrapper`?

Comment: Hello, the script is "test": "react-scripts test ", the wrapper is " wrapper = shallow(<TestedComponent {...mockProps} />)"

Comment: Is this a functional component, and if so, do you have a `displayName` set on it? (There's a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-stateless-component-name) that does this automatically if you want to try that.)

Comment: Yes, its is a functional component, there are any way to set "displayName" manually ?

Comment: Yes, it's just a property on the component, so `SomeComponent.displayName = 'SomeComponent'` ([examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43376213/5774952)).

Comment: I tried with both but test keep fail