# How do I name my React Component in Webpack export?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have tested a range of possible Webpack configurations to ensure my component is named when I build my React component. However, I am still met with this PropTypes error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `name` is marked as required in `w`, but its value is `undefined`.

How do rename my component in an export so that this error would read:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `name` is marked as required in `CustomName`, but its value is `undefined`.

I'd like the reference to be `customised` instead of `w`. I'm finding Webpack's documentation to be a little unclear.

Comment: You can use `Component.displayName = 'XYZ'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356073/how-to-set-displayname-in-a-functional-component-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because Webpack minifies your code such that the name of your component (which is just like any variable) is changed to a shorter version in order to make the bundle smaller.

You have to manually set this as a static property on your component:

```
const Customised = () => {
  // Your component
}

Customised.displayName = "Customised"
```

You can often find plugins for your build tooling (e.g. babel, esbuild) to do this automatically.

Comment: Cheers for this one. Much appreciated!